# Why react native latest version (0.60.5) does not show welcome screen in android using react native cli?

Tags: react-native

I have installed the latest version of react-native 0.60.5 using react-native CLI,  have followed all the steps. I am not getting any error in terminal or console (http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/).

Please help me if anyone facing this issue and resolved it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is showing?

Comment: Would you like to share the current screen?